# j2me Emoji Keyboard support for textfield

Tags: java-me

want to integrate Emoji character support in Textfield in j2me application. Can anyone suggest me, how can I achieve it?
For example, In whatsapp and wechat application, TextField does support Emoji keyboard characters, but in my application it shows ? for each character I type using Emoji keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the Native Font installed on your device doesn't include those emoji characters, so it's displayed as question mark.

You still can display it by embed your own Font (Bitmap Font) to your application, then draw it manually to the screen : http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_create_custom_fonts_in_Java_ME

Alternatively, you can use LWUIT library to create & incorporate Bitmap Font :

- http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.4/LWUIT_Developer_Guide_HTML/cjbcgcdd.html#cjbjcebg
- http://docs.oracle.com/javame/dev-tools/lwuit-1.4/LWUIT_Developer_Guide_HTML/cjbcgcdd.html#z400088e1296018